# Open Layers 3 mouse position detection in BNG not working

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3, map-projections

I have got the following example working on my computer:

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.1/examples/mouse-position.html

However when I change the code to use EPSG:27700 instead of either 4326 or 3857, a very simple change:

```
var mousePositionControl = new ol.control.MousePosition({
    coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(4),
    // comment the following two lines to have the mouse position
    // be placed within the map.
    projection:'EPSG:27700',
    className: 'custom-mouse-position',
    target: document.getElementById('mouse-position'),
    undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;'
  });
```

...it doesn't appear to recognise EPSG:27700 and defaults to 3857.

I have attempted to add the proj4js library by including the following at the top:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.6/proj4.js"></script>
```

As I figure OL3 might not have this projection in its default database, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like these are the only predefined projections in Proj4.js

```
instead of writing out the whole proj definition, by default proj4 has the following projections predefined:

'EPSG:4326', which has the following alias
'WGS84'
'EPSG:4269'
'EPSG:3857', which has the following aliases
'EPSG:3785'
'GOOGLE'
'EPSG:900913'
'EPSG:102113'
```

A little googling suggests that you can add it like so:

```
Proj4js.defs["EPSG:27700"] = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs";
EPSG27700 = new OpenLayers.Projection( "EPSG:27700" );
```